# Laravel runs migration even they are already migrated in migrations table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The laravel is showing weird behavior while trying to run `php artisan migrate`. There are more than 400 migrations that are already being migrated. A day back the backup of database was made and replicate of code was done. The code used backup database. So it had `migrations` table with all migrated script.

When I tried to run the command `php artisan migrate`, the migration started migrating scripts from the beginning. This caused `Base Table/View abc already exists`.

I wanted to identify the reason laravel is showing such odd behavior and solution to it.

Comment: Did you change anything in your code?

Comment: If there are any changes, like update migration structure changes or correction you made in migration will result in re-run of the migration process.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir No I didn't

Comment: @Gabriel Not change in migration structure as well

Comment: @sujit's you need to give your folder 777 permission than.

Comment: @Gabriel which folder, is it `migrations` you're pointing to?

Comment: @Sujit database folder.